# Best way to sort a numpy array based on one column then subsort based on another?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Hi I believe this is a problem best demonstrated by example.

I have a numpy array

```
array =  
[[ 101  27]
 [6  355]
 [6400 85]
 [ 33 96]]
```

I want to sort the array based on the values in the second column (ascending) to get

```
array =  
[[ 101  27]
[6400 85]
[ 33 96]
[6  355]]
```

Then I want to sort by the first column ascending but only for rows one and two. Then repeat for rows three and four.

This last step can be explained in pseudocode:

```
if array[0][0] > array[1][0]:
    transpose array[0] and array[1]
if array[2][0] > array[3][0]:
    transpose array[2] and array[3]
```

This gives:

```
array =  
[[ 101  27]
[6400 85]
[6  355]
[ 33 96]]
```

I can do this easily but the code isn't very nice, I am assuming there is a elegant/efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use built in `sorted` function in python, to accomplish the task easily,

**Try this:**

```
array = sorted(array, key=lambda x: x[1])
array[:2] = sorted(array[:2], key=lambda x: x[0]) # sort first two rows by first col
array[2:] = sorted(array[2:], key=lambda x: x[0]) # sort next two rows by first col

print(array)
```

**Output:**

```
[[101, 27],
[6400, 85], 
[6, 355], 
[33, 96]]
```